# When i call $this->loadLayout(); ite return error on catalogsearch

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, filtered-nav

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
 syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN' at line 1
```

i am use FME filtering. but its not work with catalogsearch. its return above error.